# What Resharper features should be highlighted?

Tags: resharper

On next week I will be talking in front of my colleagues about Resharper as a tool which improves developers' performance. Because time for this talk is limited the question is - what resharper features are worth to be spoken about more then the others?

At the moment I can think of:

- code analisys/highlight
- unittest runner
- refactoring features (rename, extract methods, ...?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the ones already stated, I would like to add this ones:

- Code verification and highlight the code that does not compile on the fly;
- Ctrl + Click goes to definition;
- Code suggestion/improvements (null reference exception, convert to, etc.);
- Find references is way more powerful (with go to definition and go to implementation).

I agree that a demo is probably the best, and configure the infos/errors/warnings beforehand, some of them are overkill/unused.

Comment: Code Suggestions and Go to Implementation (especially with DI/IoC) are huge.

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** (live on the beamer) what it can do: analysis, refactoring, unit test... Don't go into details as it pretty much explains itself.

Then focus on important things that they might not discover themselves: How to configure the warnings, code formatting, keyboard shortcuts. (I really love the context sensitive Ctrl-Shift-R / Alt-Enter)

Comment: My keymap does not have Ctrl-Shift-R. What does it do? =)

Comment: @DarkDeny: In the menu its called "Refactor this" You get a short list of possible refactorings depending on what you selected.

Comment: Refactor menu is great. I agree!

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing: R# lets you write clean, concise and mostly error-free code (at least when it comes to syntactical errors) and greatly lifts up a developer's productivity.

Things that seem most attractive to me:

- The many context sensitive *Refactoring* options (rename, move to another namespace, extract etc...)..
- The environment and context sensitive *Live templates*.

All these options are accessible via shortcuts (which are well worth to learn...)!

If you are doing Test-driven development, you might also find the Unit test integration noteworthy...

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

File Structur window.

Without that defining regions would not be so useful.

Answer (score 0):

- Search patterns that can be shown as errors or warnings are also pretty cool.
- Navigation (Ctrl + T, F12, Alt + Home, Alt + End,...)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871123/alternative-way-to-explore-net-framework-source-code/3871153#3871153) is one of the coolest features in R# 5.

Answer (score 0):

Go to type (Ctrl+T).

I use it in combination with "Locate in Solution Explorer" (Shift+Alt+L).

Answer (score 0):

(Ctrl + Shift + T) to find/search or open file

Answer (score 0):

This may sound sarcastic, but it's not: **The ability to disable resharper**, from Tools -> Options -> Resharper ->General -> Suspend. While resharper is awesome, it is sometimes soooooo slow. We have many different solutions, some of which are huge, and it can literally add 5 to 10 minutes to the time it takes to open and/or build our larger solutions. I love that I can `suspend` resharper when I don't need it and when working on the larger solutions, and then just re-enable it again on the days that I do need it and when I'm working in smaller solutions.

The actual features that I use most are:

- Ctrl+Shift+T to find files (works better than the VS native Ctrl+,).
- Alt+Enter for code improvements.
- The code suggestions given with blue/red squiggles.
- The little glyph it puts beside unit tests, so you can easily run a single test.
- Go To Implementation is great when working with projects using IoC.